# Write the resource-definition in the .h/.cpp file is allowed?

Tags: winapi, resources, win32gui

As we know the resource-definition is written in a resource.rc file, but my question Is it possible to write the resource-definition in .h/.cpp file instead
.rc file

For example, I want to do something similar to the following:

```
// .cpp or .h file
#define IDD_MainWindow 1 

IDD_MainWindow DIALOGEX 100, 100, 350, 150
STYLE WS_VISIBLE
BEGIN
CONTROL "", ED_ABOUT, "Static", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 4, 4, 340, 115
CONTROL "&OK", BTN_OK, "Button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 155, 120, 50, 15
END
// --------
CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MainWindow), NULL, DlgProc);
```

**Is it possible to do that or there is another way to write the resource-definition internally without .rc file?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The Microsoft resource compiler has a basic C pre-processor and [it defines a macro you can check for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/predefined-macros).

```
#define MYICONID 42
#ifdef RC_INVOKED
MYICONID  ICON "myicon.ico"
#else
#include <Windows.h>
int main(...)
{
  LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(MYICONID), ...);
  ...
}
#endif
```

You can then feed this file into rc.exe **and** cl.exe. This will of course still generate a .res file that you have to include when linking.